# A problem of decidability (predicate metalogic)

Tags: predicate-logic, metalogic

I have been stumped by the following and would greatly appreciate any hints or advice as to how to proceed:

For some first-order predicate logic system:

Let Γ be a decidable set of wffs such that for any closed wff σ, either Γ|= σ or Γ|= ¬σ (but not both). Prove that the set of all closed wffs deducible from Γ is decidable.

Here '|=' is taken to mean the consequent is deducible from the antecedent, and wff=well-formed formula.

Thanks to anyone who takes a stab - it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We give a very informal argument. Let $\Delta$ be the set of all closed formulas deducible from $\Gamma$.

We can list all proofs from $\Gamma$ as a sequence $\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3,\dots$. (Proofs are certain sequences of sentences.) For each proof $\pi_i$, check whether $\alpha$ or $\lnot\alpha$ is the last sentence in $\pi_i$. Since one of $\alpha$ or $\lnot\alpha$ is provable from $\Gamma$, this process will terminate, and give us a (very inefficient) decision procedure for membership in $\Delta$.

Comment: Thanks, Andre! My concerns lie in your statement "this process will terminate." I follow you up to that point, but who's to say the sequence <π_1,π_2,π_3...> terminates? If it did not, our procedure would not terminate, but continue checking whether α or ¬α is that last sentence in some π_i, correct?

Comment: If all possible proofs are listed, then  the completeness condition on $\Gamma$  (for any $\alpha$, one of $\alpha$ or $\lnot \alpha$ is provable from $\Gamma$) **guarantees** that some day $i$, one of $\alpha$ or $\lnot\alpha$ will be the terminal sentence of $\pi_i$. We do not know **when** this will happen, but it is certain that it will happen, so the algorithm terminates.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for taking the time to walk me through this! :)

Comment: You are welcome. Listing  proofs is tricky. Let the length of a proof from $\Gamma$ be the number of symbols used. List all proofs of length $\le 1$ that possibly use $\gamma_1$ as an axiom, say alphabetically (there are none, but never mind). Then  list all proofs of length $\le 2$ that possibly use $\gamma_1$ or $\gamma_2$ as axioms. And so on. We can algorithmically decide whether a sequence of symbols is a proof that possibly uses some of $\gamma_1$ to $\gamma_k$. So we can algorithmically list all proofs from $\Gamma$, since a proof uses at most a finite number of the $\gamma_i$.